# Export methods of Class in ES6

Tags: javascript

I have the following class.

```
export class Emitter {

  constructor() {
      this.events = {};
  }

  off(eventName, callBack) {
    console.log(this); //{}
  }
}
```

How can I use the off method inside of the following statement within the same file?

```
export function off() {

}
```

Or is there any better/cleaner way to do this?

**PS. They will be imported in a different file and tested**

```
import * as Emitter from '../src/emitter';
Emitter.off(EVENT_NAME_ONE)
```

Comment: Don't use a class? ... kidding (but not really)

Comment: is `Emitter.off` is static method? where is the code for that?

Answer (score 2):

Method `off` of `Emitter` should be static:

```js
export class Emitter {

  constructor() {
      this.events = {};
  }

  static off(eventName, callBack) {
    console.log(this); //{}
  }
}


export const off = (eventName, callBack) => {
    return Emitter.off(eventName, callBack)
}
```

And the import sould be:

```
import { off } from '../src/emitter';
```